# add and remove divs with button jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need a little help with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zWkxt/6/
So basically I want functionality to add and remove divs with buttons.
Always remove visible div with biggest number and add div that is next...

```
<button class="add">add</button>
<button class="remove">remove</button>
<div class="targetdiv">
    <div class="special">div 1</div>
    <div class="special">div 2</div>
    <div class="special">div 3</div>
    <div class="special">div 4</div>
    <div class="special">div 5</div>
    <div class="special">div 6</div>
</div>

jQuery(function () {
    var save = $('.special').detach();
    $('.add').click(function() {
            save.eq(0).appendTo(".targetdiv");
            save = save.filter(function(i) { return i; });
    });


    $('.remove').click(function() {
           $('.special').last().detach();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please give more explanation as to what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Well the easier approach would be to convert that collection into array and manipulate that way, here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zWkxt/11/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you append an object, it gets removed from your variable, thats why you can just do save.eq(0) .... otherwise, you'd have to walk through it.

A couple of ways to solve it, you could clone it and insert the clone, then move the next index.

Or, you can add it back to the save array.
Like this:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var save = $('.special').detach();
    $('.add').click(function() {
   
            save.eq(0).appendTo(".targetdiv");
            save = save.filter(function(i) { return i; });
             
    });
    
    
    
    $('.remove').click(function() {
   
         save.push($('.special').last().detach()[0]); //Add it back to the array
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<button class="remove">remove</button>
<div class="targetdiv">
    <div class="special">div 1</div>
    <div class="special">div 2</div>
    <div class="special">div 3</div>
    <div class="special">div 4</div>
    <div class="special">div 5</div>
    <div class="special">div 6</div>
</div>
```

This one keeps the order:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var osave = $('.special').detach();
    var save=[]
    for(i=0;i<osave.length;i++){

        save[i]=osave[i]; //Fix key reference
    }
    
    $('.add').click(function() {
            //get the first index of the array
            index=Object.keys(save).sort()[0];
            console.log(save,index);   
            $(save).eq(index).appendTo(".targetdiv");
            save.splice(index,1); //truly remove from save
            //save = save.filter(function(i) { return i; });
           
             
    });
    
    
    
    $('.remove').click(function() {
         //How many are visible?
         vis=$('.special').length-1;
         save[vis]=($('.special').last().detach()[0]); //Add it back to the array with the right index.
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<button class="remove">remove</button>
<div class="targetdiv">
    <div class="special">div 1</div>
    <div class="special">div 2</div>
    <div class="special">div 3</div>
    <div class="special">div 4</div>
    <div class="special">div 5</div>
    <div class="special">div 6</div>
</div>
```

The way this one works is it assigns the keys to the save, making sure it can keep the reference, then as it adds them to the document, it removes them from save. As you remove them from the doc, it adds it back to save with the correct indexes.

Better version:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var osave = $('.special').detach();
    var save=[]
    for(i=0;i<osave.length;i++){

        save[i]=osave[i]; //Fix key reference
    }
    
    $('.add').click(function() {
            //get the first index of the array
            //index=Object.keys(save).sort()[0];
            index=$('.special').length;
            $(save).eq(index).appendTo(".targetdiv");
            //Dont remove from save.
            //save = save.filter(function(i) { return i; });
           
             
    });
    
    
    
    $('.remove').click(function() {


         $('.special').last().detach()[0]; //Add it back to the array with the right index.
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">add</button>
<button class="remove">remove</button>
<div class="targetdiv">
    <div class="special">div 1</div>
    <div class="special">div 2</div>
    <div class="special">div 3</div>
    <div class="special">div 4</div>
    <div class="special">div 5</div>
    <div class="special">div 6</div>
</div>
```

This one doesn't manage the save variable, only manages the index by seeing what's currently in view, assuming nothing gets out of order.

I recommend the last one, but leaving the others in the answer incase you need something from them.